# Getting closest place using google places api under iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

It seems to me several things I can do using google places web service api, cannot be done using google places ios sdk.

What I want to achieve is just getting the closest pizzeria and its information like address and telephone number. I don't use maps. 
I don't see in the iOS sdk a method or class to search places close a specific location with several conditions (like type=restaurant and keyword=pizza).
However I can do that using the web service directly, without an sdk, but of course requires more code.

Am I right? Is that normal? I mean, that the iOS version has not the same functionality than the webservice, while I guess it is just a wrapper of the web service.

Web service sdk:
https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search

iOS sdk:
https://developers.google.com/places/ios/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Places API for iOS doesn't support "condition" likes types or keywords.

You can however implement [autocomplete.](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/autocomplete)

> The autocomplete service in the Google Places API for iOS returns
>   place predictions in response to a text-based location search query.
>   The request includes a textual search string and optional filter
>   criteria. You can use this service to provide autocomplete
>   functionality as the user types, by returning places such as
>   businesses, addresses and points of interest.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why it's not included that functionality. So I have to use its web service API :(